# Memory Leak Rails + Sidekiq + Heroku + jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, memory-leaks, sidekiq

I'm currently fetching massive amounts of crypto hourly prices for the past two years of a certain currency pair. I've used Sidekiq to this concurrently for multiple coins.

The problem is that as I am using jsonb to store the information, I suspect that it is causing a big memory leak. But I maybe wrong and my Active Record queries are not optimised.

The resulting factor is that my Heroku Workers are consistently getting over the quota and shutting down.

```
def get_2_years_of_btc_data(coin_id)
        begin
            time_batches = [1451606400,1458810000,1466013600,1473217200,1480420800,1487624400,1494828000,1502031600,1509235200,1516438800,1523642400]
            time_batches.each do |time| 
                 sync_hourly_btc_data(coin_id,time)                 
            end
        rescue => e
            #ScrapeLog.create(error: e.message, process: "Cryptocompare - Sync Coin Prices", resource: "coin", resource_id: coin_id)
        end
    end

def sync_hourly_btc_data(coin_id,floored_timestamp)
    coin = Coin.find(coin_id)
    snap = coin.snap        
    response = HTTParty.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym=#{coin.ticker}&aggregate=1&tsym=BTC&limit=2000&toTs=#{floored_timestamp}")
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    data = json["Data"]
    if snap.btc_counter_cache < 1
        snap.to_btc = data
    else
        new_data = data.select {|data| data["time"] > snap.btc_to_ts} 
        snap.to_btc = snap.to_btc + new_data
    end
    snap.btc_from_ts = snap.to_btc.first["time"]
    snap.btc_to_ts = snap.to_btc.last["time"]
    snap.coin.real_price_btc = snap.to_btc.last["close"]
    snap.btc_counter_cache = snap.to_btc.size
    snap.save
end
```

**Snaps** is the table that stores the price information for each coin and **to_btc** is the jsonb column that stores all the data.

I need help knowing if this is a common jsonb problem when it grows in size or my Active Record queries are inefficient.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey T.
Have you measured how long does it take for the response to come back, and how massive the returned data actually is?
Also, is this a BG job? This batch size is 11 different requests and Heroku warns that all requests that take longer than 500ms should be inside a BG job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like jsonb is the issue here. I am assuming that the code presented is the actual worker, so my first pass here would be to enqueue a worker *per* time batch. The way you are currently doing this will have to hold all the API responses in memory, it seems.

So if you enqueue a job/worker per each time batch, you can processed each response individually - given some backoff between workers (enqueue to run with 2 minutes or something apart), you should be fine.

I imagine that is the data is that big, that select traversal you are doing is also rather expensive